# Custom cell with UISearchController in UITableViewController (result controller)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to implement a UISearchController (not UISearchDisplayController which is deprecated)

I face a ridiculously time eating issue.

When I try to `dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier` it doesn't works with my `CellAutocompletion` (UITableViewCell subclassing)

Like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]

    let cell:CellAutocompletion = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("suggestionCell") as! CellAutocompletion

    cell.itemLabel?.text = item.item_name;

    return cell
}
```

This throw me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

**BUT** when I do this :

```
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "suggestionCell");
```

It works. So with a Default iOS cell, it works, with my custom cell not. Any idea?

I think I ask the wrong tableview but considering I am inside a TableviewController included inside UISearchController which is used by another VC, I am lost.

**My main VC** which instanciate my searchController and the TableViewController where I have issue.

```
    //ViewDidLoad
    resultsTableController = ProductResultTabController();
    resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController);
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true;

    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

**My CustomCell Class**

```
class CellAutocompletion:UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var parentItemLabel: UILabel!

}
```

**ProductResultTabController** (subclass of TableViewController)

```
class ProductResultTabController: UITableViewController {
var filteredProducts = [ITEM]();

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredProducts.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]

    let cell:CellAutocompletion = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("suggestionCell") as! CellAutocompletion!

    cell.itemLabel?.text = item.item_name;

    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: Does your resultsTableController exist in code or in the storyboard? If the former, is your cell prototyped in the storyboard? If the latter, does your tableView call `registerNib:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier` ?

Comment: The resultController exists both in code and storyboard, I've associated it with a TableViewController in storyboard, and in my main VC to the searchController `self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController);` And Cell is prototyped, and associated to my custom Cell Class (and IBoutlet linked too)

Comment: Yes but you're calling init like so `resultsTableController = ProductResultTabController();` Could you post the code for `ProductResultTabController`

Comment: Ok, answer incoming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand, your `ProductResultTabController` lives in the storyboard with the cell prototype. As a consequence, call `resultsTableController = ProductResultTabController()` doesn't do the most essential part of creating a `TableViewController`, which is registering your tableView: for a class or nib. You could create your cell in a nib and call `tableview.registerNib:` in your PRTC `viewDidLoad:`, but there is an other, slightly more convenient way:

1. Create your PRTC in the storyboard and prototype the cell (I believe you've already done that)
2. In SB, go to attributes inspector and give the controller a storyboard ID

[image: Giving a storyboard ID in Attributes Inspector]

3 - In your main VC's `viewDidLoad:`, replace resultsTableController = ProductResultTabController()`by the following:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
resultsTableController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(myStoryboardID)
```